# Handling clicks on notification button and the notification part itself in android

Tags: android, notifications

[image]

I've a notification which says "Now Playing : Radio " and it has a stop button below this. When the user clicks on stop button, the audio stops and now what I'm trying to achieve is when the user clicks on the notification part above the stop button I want to open a fragment. I'm showing the notification like this.

```
Intent notIntent = new Intent();
    notIntent.setAction(ACTION_STOP);
    PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getService(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(),
            notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification n = builder.setContentIntent(pendInt)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.music_nepal_not)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(BackgroundAudioService.this, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setTicker("Playing Live Radio")
            .setContentTitle("Now Playing : Live Radio ")
            .addAction(R.layout.toggle_notification, "", pendInt)
            .build(); 
    notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
n.addContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

This would get triggered when the user clicks on the notification body. `pendingIntent` would be a `PendingIntent` to your `Activity` hosting the fragment since, those bastards cannot exist without activities. Similarly, you can add that `pendingIntent` to your `addAction()`.